# Cannot parse url string for Microsoft graph because using the Invoke-MSGraphRequest command and query parameters

Tags: string, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I cannot parse and make a call using the current URL because when I use the $filter and $select query parameters it breaks the string, yet it works great in Postman and give me all the data I needed.

```
Connect-MSGraph
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$select=emailaddress,id,imei,operatingSystem,ownerType,managedDeviceOwnerType&$filter=(operatingSystem eq 'iOS')" -HttpMethod GET
```

I need to filter these devices then if the ownership is personal, I was going to use graph API again to Update the object device using PATCH. Please help with this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Escape the literal `$` character in `$select` and `$filter` with a backtick: ```https://host/path?`$select=emailaddress,...```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate solution to your problem is to simply escape the verbatim `$`'s with a backtick `` ` ``:

```
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?`$select=emailaddress,id,imei,operatingSystem,ownerType,managedDeviceOwnerType&`$filter=(operatingSystem eq 'iOS')" -HttpMethod GET
```

Or to use single-quotes `'` to avoid PowerShell attempting to expand what *looks* like variables - literal single-quotes inside the URL will have to be escaped by *doubling* them:

```
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$select=emailaddress,id,imei,operatingSystem,ownerType,managedDeviceOwnerType&$filter=(operatingSystem eq ''iOS'')' -HttpMethod GET
```

That being said, I'd personally recommend constructing the query parameters from simpler parts:

```
$endpointURL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices'

# assign variable parts of the filter to a variable
$targetOperatingSystem = 'iOS'

# construct a hashtable containing all the query parameters
$GraphParameters = [ordered]@{
  '$select' = 'emailaddress,id,imei,operatingSystem,ownerType,managedDeviceOwnerType'
  '$filter' = "(operatingSystem eq '$targetOperatingSystem')"
}

# construct query string and final URL from the individual parts above
$queryString = $GraphParameters.GetEnumerator().ForEach({ $_.Key,$_.Value -join '=' }) -join '&'
$URL = $endpointURL,$queryString -join '?'
```

And then finally invoke `Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url $URL -HttpMethod Get`

Comment: I now get an error ```Invoke-MSGraphRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Url'. The provided URL is not valid - the URL may be a relative URL
At C:\Users\Admin.MH\Desktop\powershell\graph\deviceOwnership\getDevices.ps1:33 char:28
+ Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url $URL -HttpMethod Get
+                            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-MSGraphRequest], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Intune.PowerShellGraphSDK.PowerShellCmdlets.InvokeRequest```

Comment: it'' work with one query param but not two. So this ``` 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?select=id,imei,operatingSystem,ownerType,managedDeviceOwnerType' `` returns @odata.context

Comment: Something helpful I wish I knew before asking >> On the beta endpoint, the $ prefix is optional. For example, instead of $filter, you can use filter. On the v1 endpoint, the $ prefix is optional for only a subset of APIs. For simplicity, always include $ if using the v1 endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

Comment: Does anybody get following URI working: Invoke-MSGraphRequest -Url "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/roleScopeTags?`$filter=displayName eq 'test'" -Verbose

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having trouble with Invoke-MSGraphRequest with error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Url'...

then

1. Use backtick before $ as mentioned in the answer above (like **`$filter**)
2. instead of using **whitespaces** in the URL, use html encoding **%20**.

**So instead of:**

```
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations?`$filter=userId eq 'XXX'"
```

**Use:**

```
Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/managedAppRegistrations?`$filter=userId%20eq%20'XXX'"
```